# Wait for a second on each loop

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, concurrency, timer

I have program that I want it to do each code then wait and then do next code
here is my codes:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim msg() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "e"}

    For Each item In msg
        MessageBox.Show(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

if I want to write a simple pseudocode, it would be like this:

```
for each item in msg
    print(item)
    wait one second
next item
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mark the method as async.

```
for each item in msg
    print(item)
    await Task.Delay(1000)//Await a second
next item
```

For framework restrictions if you cant use async feature you'll have to do that with timer or some other mechanism.

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim msg() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "e"}

    For Each item In msg
        MessageBox.Show(item)
        Await Task.Delay(1000)//Await a second
    Next
End Sub
```

`Task.Delay(1000)` will return a `Task` which will eventually reach completion after provided milliseconds(1000 in this case). We're awaiting(asynchronously waiting) on that task. To enable `Await` feature you need to mark the method as `Async`.

This will guide you how [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) works.

---

For .net 4.0, and who can't use Bcl.Async pack following code will help.

```
public class PeriodicEnumerator<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<T> sequence;
    private Action<T> action;
    private int period;
    private System.Threading.Timer timer;
    private SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext;
    private IEnumerator<T> enumerator;
    private TaskCompletionSource<object> completionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    public PeriodicEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action, int period)
        : this(sequence, action, period, null)
    {

    }

    public PeriodicEnumerator(IEnumerable<T> sequence, Action<T> action, int period, SynchronizationContext synchronizationContext)
    {
        this.sequence = sequence;
        this.action = action;
        this.period = period;
        this.synchronizationContext = synchronizationContext;

        this.timer = new System.Threading.Timer(TimerCallback);
    }

    public Task Enumerate()
    {
        if (this.enumerator != null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Enumeration already started");
            //To avoid multiple enumerations, better create new instance
        }
        enumerator = sequence.GetEnumerator();
        timer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);

        return completionSource.Task;
    }

    private void TimerCallback(object state)
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            completionSource.SetResult(null);
            timer.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            T current = enumerator.Current;
            if (synchronizationContext != null)
            {
                synchronizationContext.Send((x) => action(current), null);
            }
            else
            {
                action(current);
            }
            timer.Change(period, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            completionSource.SetException(ex);
            timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Usecase:

```
static void ConsoleAppSample()
{
    var periodicEnumerator = new PeriodicEnumerator<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5), (x) => Console.WriteLine(x), 1000);
    Task enumerationTask = periodicEnumerator.Enumerate();
    enumerationTask.Wait();//Optionally wait for completion
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
    Console.Read();
}

static void SynchronizationContextSample()//applicable for any UI apps
{
    var periodicEnumerator = new PeriodicEnumerator<int>(Enumerable.Range(1, 5), (x) => textbox.Text = x.ToString(), 1000,SynchronizationContext.Current);
    Task enumerationTask = periodicEnumerator.Enumerate();
    Console.WriteLine("Completed");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Code is pretty simple, I believe no explanation required :) If anything drop a comment.

1. Notice that `Enumerate` method returns a task, so that you may wait
   on it, or attach a continuation or whatever. (You may add
   cancellation feature etc).
2. Also support for GUI applications to make sure callback is fired in
   UI thread(given SynchronizationContext) if any provided, so that you
   can update UI in callback easily.

P.S: apologizes for c# code, am basically c# guy, It will take days for me to code in Vb.Net :p

Comment: Sorry I'm very new to vb.net can you please explain it more simply? thanks anyway

Comment: @EmPlusPlus I think you should go with Sriram Sakthivel. This method is more reliable then other.

Comment: @EmPlusPlus Updated my answer, apologizes if any syntax error; am basically c# guy :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Thank you. I just tried this code but unfortunately I can't use Async. It's because I am using VS2010. I read in the link you provided, that it's for VS2012 an higher versions

Comment: Then you're struck :( You need to use timer setup 1 second interval, show single message in every tick event. Stop the timer when you finished showing all

Comment: Yes! exactly! I should use timer instead of for loop! Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you update your answer with this method for others, please.

Comment: @EmPlusPlus I hope you would have already fixed your problem, I've updated my answer as per request which works in .net 4.0, can be further downgraded to with considerable feature loss. You may consider using it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by making thread sleep for some seconds as shown below

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: You're sleeping 1/1000 of a second, not `some seconds as shown below`. ;)

Comment: `Sleep` takes milli second as parameter ;)

Comment: Your answer is correct but sleep is something that we should be avoiding in our production code

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I actually don't want to use sleep.

Answer (score 1):

I have used thread in my code becuase sleep will hang the application.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim thread As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf ShowMessage)
    thread.IsBackground = True
    thread.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub ShowMessage()
    Dim msg() As String = {"a", "b", "c", "e"}
    For each item As String In msg
        MessageBox.Show(item)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Next
End Sub
```